# symfony 6 Cannot autowire service: argument has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm working on a symfony 6.3 project. I'm trying to use a custom service from a controller.

This service needs some config params defined in .env file.

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Services\Authentication\Auth": argument "$region" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing to be able to use it?

These are my files:

My service file:

```
class Auth implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var string */
    private $version;

    /** @var string */
    private $region;

    public function __construct(
        $version,
        $region
    ){
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->region = $region;
}
```

the services.yaml

```
parameters:
    version: '%env(resolve:VERSION)%'
    region: '%env(resolve:REGION)%'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 

    App\Services\Authentication\Auth: ['@api.auth']
    
    api.auth:
        class: App\Services\Authentication\Auth
        arguments:
            $version: "%version%"
            $region: "%region%"
```

And I've defined the service in the __construct controller to use it:

```
public function __construct(
        private Auth $auth
    ) {
    }
```

**SOLUTION**
services.yaml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true   
        autoconfigure: true

    api.auth:
        class: App\Services\Authentication\Auth
        arguments:
            $version: "%version%"
            $region: "%region%"

    App\Controller\ApiController:
        arguments: 
            $auth: '@api.auth'
```

Comment: What is your php version ?

Comment: What does the value of `REGION` look like compared to `VERSION`?

Comment: `App\Services\Authentication\Auth: '@api.auth'`?

Comment: Why do you have two configurations for the same service?

Comment: First problem is you declare `$version` and `$region` in an array (using `-` so the container does not initialize your service with arguments but with an array of arguments)

Second issue is that you alias your service, and so, you should refer to this alias when you need to inject the service.

Answer (score 2):

First problem is you declare `$version` and `$region` in an array (using `-` so the container does not initialize your service with arguments but with an array of arguments)

Second issue is that you alias your service, and so, you should refer to this alias when you need to inject the service.

First of all I don't think you provide the full code here since you implements the `EventSubscriberInterface` but never declare the `getSubscribedEvents` method.

So I'll suggest you just have removed this part of the code from your exemple, otherway you'd obtain an error such as

> Error: Class App\Services\Authentication\Auth contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

So I'll assume this subscriber actually subscribe to some events to pass this error.

Anyway, the error is coming from your usage of this service from the controller which should then be defined in the service configuration.

The missing configuration in your service is you need to give the specific service alias that should be used when container is building dependencies:

```
# services.yaml

    api.auth:
        class: App\Service\Authentication\Auth
        arguments:
            $version: "version"
            $region: "region"

    App\Controller\FooBarController:
        arguments:
            $auth: '@api.auth'
```

##### Detailed answer using a sample FooBarController

With a `FooBarController` such as the following :

```
...
class FooBarController extends AbstractController
{
    public function __construct(private Auth $auth) {}

    #[\Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route(path: '/foo-bar', name: '_foo_bar')]
    public function fooBarAction()
    {...}
}
```

With the following configuration:

```
# services.yaml
...
    App\Service\Authentication\Auth:
        arguments:
            - $version: "version"
            - $region: "region"
```

The container will initialize the `FooBarController` with an empty constructor (resultin in your error):

```php
# ContainerIVupgpF\getFooBarControllerService.php
...
$container->services['App\\Controller\\FooBarController'] = $instance = new \App\Controller\FooBarController();
```

With the following service definition, here's how the container is initialized:

```
# services.yaml

    api.auth:
        class: App\Service\Authentication\Auth
        arguments:
            $version: "version"
            $region: "region"

    App\Controller\FooBarController:
        arguments:
            $auth: '@api.auth'
```

```php
# ContainerR8OkFVK\getFooBarControllerService.php
...
$container->services['App\\Controller\\FooBarController'] = $instance = new \App\Controller\FooBarController(new \App\Service\Authentication\Auth('version', 'region'));
```

Comment: What do you mean I just tried this on a Symfony 6.3 project and I reproduced and fixed the error. Autowiring can't guess how to inject untyped parameters and that's why you should configure the arguments of the controller to inject this service.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @vincentPHILIPPE! I changed services.yaml following your instructions but the same error is happening...
`App\Services\Authentication\Auth: ['@api.auth']
api.auth:
    class: App\Services\Authentication\Auth
    arguments:
        $version: "latest"
        $region: "us-west-2"

App\Controller\ApiController:
    arguments: 
        $auth: '@api.auth'`
I've tried passing only one param (version) and it worked. But when I add region, it happens again

Comment: Can you check how the controller is initialized in the container ? 

The service should be initialized in the `ContainerXXXXXX\getXXXXXXControllerService.php`

Comment: $container->services['App\\Controller\\ApiController'] = $instance = new \App\Controller\ApiController(($container->privates['api.auth'] ??= new \App\Services\Authentication\Auth('latest')));

Comment: Remove this declaration from your service configuration

`App\Services\Authentication\Auth: ['@api.auth']`

Please update your question instead of submiting code in comment since it's less readable :)

Comment: @vincent - the controller is already autowired - adding it doesnt change anything..  the only thing you changed afterwards was removing the array notation from the arguments like you saw in my answer... 
the next thing is - using aliases is not needed in almost all cases. my version from my answer will work - when `Auth::class` is used in the constructor it will load the right service.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to inject a event_subscriber in the controller in the first place?

But anyway, try this:

```
App\Services\Authentication\Auth:
    arguments:
        $version: "foo"
        $region: "bar"
    tags:
        - {name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

The alias is pointless.. remove it.

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#services-wire-specific-service for more information.

or a little pro tip, if you need this arguments in more classes...

you can do this:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        bind:
            $appVersion: '%env(MYVERSION)%'
```

then appVersion is autoinjected in every class which uses it. without having to dedicate declaring it. this helps cleaning up your service.yml.